# Passing combobox selection as a variable?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a very simple form that copies the contents of one directory to a USB flash drive. I have a single combo box populated with available drive letters, and a button to execute.

What I want to do (and where I am getting stuck) is to use xcopy to copy files from one static location (a networked directory) to the drive selected in the combo box.

I know this is probably pretty remedial, but hoping someone can help.

I have been trying to pass it as a variable, but am having all sorts of trouble (which is probably because I don't really know what I am doing yet.

Any suggestions for a wannabe self-taught dev?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cmbDrives.DataSource = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();

        int num = 1;
        long bigNum = num;
        1 = cmbDrives.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: What does it mean `1 = cmbDrives.SelectedValue;` ?

Comment: what the HECK does this line do `1 = cmbDrives.SelectedValue`

Comment: I am trying to set 1 as the selected value of the combobox. cmdDrives is the combobox (sorry I didnt specify that in my OP.

EDIT : Like I said, I am very very new and might be considered borderline retarded. I do not mind being told so. : )

Comment: you need to learn how to assign values to a variable so remove the `1` and replace it with num. also initialize num = 0 and convert the selected value from string to Int

Comment: ^^^ That is exactly right. Thank you for the information. I am trying to run before I can walk, but info like this is priceless to me.

Comment: c# should allow values to be assigned to literals really

Answer (score 3):

from your comments : if you want to set the second item(index 1) as the selected item

Replace This:

```
1 = cmbDrives.SelectedValue;
```

With this:

```
cmbDrives.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

**Note :** Index is zero based , so you need to assign 0 to select the first Item

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. And you'll want to put this in the button click handler:

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string destinationDrive = cmbDrives.SelectedValue.ToString();

    Process.Start("xcopy", string.Format("/someswitch {0} otherarguments", destinationDrive));
}
```

All that's left is to wire up the event handler. You can do this in the designer or in the Form1() constructor:

```
btnGo.Click += btnGo_Click;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I know the flow of what I want to happen, I am just learning the language. Thank you so much for being patient and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to show Combobox item which has "1" value on load event. If it is the case,

```
cmbDrives.SelectedValue="1";
```

Comment: I would add a conditional check incase SelectedValue = -1 then assign it num = 1

Comment: and what this does? `SelectedValue` is not an `int`.

Comment: This is worse, won't even compile. though your former version will have compiled but runtime exception will be thrown.

Comment: @Nanosoft I think you're thinking of `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedValue`.

Comment: OMG ! I answered hurriedly and got to answer you people. SelectedValue  is a string and SelectedIndex is an int. Well I formerly Converted it to int to assign to int num, but when @SriramSakthivel asked whether SelectedValue wasn't int, I confused with SelectedIndex. Neither the SelectedValue would be converted to int as it's some text nor SelectedValue implicitly could be assigned to num. Mistake in hurry guys.